# Эффект частичного складывания изображения при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Даже и не знаю, как это охарактеризовать, но вот что нужно сделать при наведении на изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реально ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.folded {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
.folded-itm {
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  background: url(https://i1.wallbox.ru/wallpapers/preview/201243/devushki-c67fe6c5a8dd.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.folded:hover .folded-itm:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  box-shadow: inset 20px 0 50px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
.folded:hover .folded-itm:nth-child(even) {
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
  box-shadow: inset 20px 0 50px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}

.folded .folded-itm:nth-child(1) {
  background-position: 0;
}
.folded .folded-itm:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: -80px;
}
.folded .folded-itm:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: -160px;
}
.folded .folded-itm:nth-child(4) {
  background-position: -240px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="folded">
 <li class="folded-itm"></li>
 <li class="folded-itm"></li>
 <li class="folded-itm"></li>
 <li class="folded-itm"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что именно сгладить...

Answer (score 5):

Присоседиться что ли к @vantal? Собственно, вот:

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #fafafb;}

.stack {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -80px; margin-left: -250px; text-align: center; transition: all 2.5s}

.stack span {float: left; display: block; width: 100px; height: 120px; line-height: 120px; background: #bcbbbb; color: #bcbbbb; font-weight: bold; font-size: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; transition: all 1.2s;}

.stack span:nth-child(1) {border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;}
.stack span:nth-child(5) {border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;}

.stack:hover span:nth-child(even) {transform: skewY(15deg); color: #f48024; box-shadow: 0 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0px 0 130px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);}
.stack:hover span:nth-child(odd) {transform: skewY(-15deg); color: #f48024; box-shadow: 0 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);}

.stack:hover {transform: rotateX(25deg)}

.stack:hover span {text-shadow: -0 -1px 0 darkgray, 0 -1px 0 darkgray, -0 1px 0 darkgray, 0 1px 0 darkgray, -1px -0 0 darkgray, 1px -0 0 darkgray, -1px 0 0 darkgray, 1px 0 0 darkgray, -1px -1px 0 darkgray, 1px -1px 0 darkgray, -1px 1px 0 darkgray, 1px 1px 0 darkgray, -1px -1px 0 darkgray, 1px -1px 0 darkgray, -1px 1px 0 darkgray, 1px 1px 0 darkgray;}
```

```html
<div class="stack"><span>S</span><span>T</span><span>A</span><span>C</span><span>K</span></div>
```

Comment: Есть вариант как пофиксить зазоры между `span` при skew?)

Comment: Проскакивают периодически, где-то в середине анимации, на FF видать)

Comment: В хроме тоже заметно, но там меньше.